# Recursive overflow

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have a problem that gives Stack Overflow Error on my code. I'm trying to find a number in one array, but I have to do it in a recursive function, and gives that error.

```
public static int linear(int[] array, int num, int indice) {
    if (indice < array.length-1) {
        if (array[indice] == num) {
            return indice;
        } else {
            ocurrencias++;
            linear(array, num, indice + 1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you can help me I would appreciate. My english is a little rusty, sorry.

Comment: What's the size of your array? If you are running into stackoverflow just use a simple for loop. If you have to use recursion, you will want to sort the array and use a binary search algorithm.

Comment: How long is the array?

Comment: the size of the array is inserted before by the user. And i have to use linear search to find the number, but using recursive function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a return before the recursive call to linear, don't you?

```
return linear(array, num, indice + 1);
```

However, I don't think Java does tail-recursion-optimization
([What is tail recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion)),
so you have to increase your stack-size appropriately for huge arrays ;)

Comment: I had the return statement before "linear" but error appear as well. The variable indice starts at 0 and should increment until it is lower than array.length-1. If the array have 100 positions indice should stop at 99.